# angular-ui-router change data object on $state.go()

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do you make the state ui provider data object

```
  .state('app', {
            controller: 'Ctrl',
            templateUrl: 'app/widgets/views/widget.html',
            data: {
                data: 'property'
            }

        })
```

I've tried doing it this way but it doesn't work.

```
  .state('app.list', {
            params: {
              dataAssign: null,
            },
            controller: 'OtherCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'app/widgets/views/list.html',
            data: {
                data: this.params.dataAssign
            }

        })
```

Basically I need to assign the data from the $state.go() function. And there doesn't seem to be a way. It needs to be the data object is because I'm using the angular-ui-router-styles plugin and it uses the data object to get the paths to the stylesheet.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this will work, but you can try the following:

Use [State Change Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) to intercept the state transition

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
    toState.data.data = toParams.dataAssign;
});
```

Then you'd call `$state.go()` like:

```
$state.go('app.list', {dataAssign: someData});
```

Logically it seems like it should work but let me know if it doesn't.

**Update:**

Note that this will happen for all state transitions. So if you don't want that to be the case then you can check the state name using `toState.name`.

Comment: brilliant, i'll check that out

Comment: It Works!! now i have a theme changer! Thank you so much

Comment: Great. Glad I could help.